# Filling an array of integers by one prompting

Tags: java

How to fill an array of integers in Java  by asking the user to enter the  number once ?

for example :

- Enter 3 integers >: 123

then I want to get the array filled like that :

```
arr[0]=1
arr[1]=2
arr[2]=3
```

I hope the question is clear :)

rgds

Comment: This is where you start by showing us what you have tried, how it didn't work and what you were expecting the results to be. There are literally thousands of sites/threads telling you how to do this.

Comment: So you want only single digit numbers? Because `12, 23, and 123` are also integers.

Comment: Also, are you having trouble reading input from the user? Or are you having trouble taking the String and making integers?

Comment: @redFIVE I am learning and no body can learn without asking ! I've spent about an hour thinking how to solve it then i posted the question ... thanks for understanding :)

Comment: Guys, this is a homework assignment. Do not solve it for him! Otherwise you end up with co-workers who will not even know how to do this! I warned you! ;-)

Comment: @TFuto will i've got the answer .. but don't try to be smarter than others by the way it is not a homework assignment .

Comment: @iShaalan: the proper way to approach this is to find out what you do not know. You have to know using user input, arrays, loops, String to number conversion. You have to demonstrate all of your skills in these. And if you had these, you would probably know the answer for your question. If not, then others could help to debug that. But submitting a question, grabbing an answer helps you get nowhere. It may be easy now, but when you get a real job, all those frustations that you avoided now will happen the very same time, simultaneously. I warned you! :-) And others as well...

Comment: ...and BTW: you accepted @Surveon's answer - well that works only with single digits. How would you expand that to multi-digit numbers? You simply cannot hack it. You will have to create your own generic solution from scratch, which actually gives you a better understanding of Java. Just trying to help...

Comment: I learned *without* asking questions you can learn with minimal effort. I'm not going to do your homework for you, as there is no way on earth this isn't a homework assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of going about this would be to take the integer in as a `String`. You can then use `toCharArray()` in order to grab an array of the characters - these characters can then be individually parsed into `Integer` by utilizing `Character.getNumericValue()`.

See the [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) and [Character](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) APIs for more details on those methods.

Small example of what I mean:

```
String numbers = "123";
char[] numArray = numbers.toCharArray();

for (char c : numArray) {
    int num = Character.getNumericValue(c);
    // Do what you will with the number.
}
```

As noted, this particular implementation would only work in this format if you are assuming that each integer is single digit.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:-

```
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

   System.out.println("How many numbers do you want to enter?");
    int num = input.nextInt();

    int array[] = new int[num];

    System.out.println("Enter the " + num + " numbers now.");

    for (int i = 0 ; i < array.length; i++ ) {
       array[i] = input.nextInt();
    }
```

Comment: I don't get why people answer questions that had literally no effort put in on OP's part.

Comment: `by asking the user to enter the number once ` You've broken this requirement